# Is it possible to find character width in a string (sentence or word) in SVG

Tags: javascript, string, svg, two.js

I am trying to make a dynamic text editor in SVG using two.js, I have a custom blinking cursor (cursor functionality, it is same as input field in HTML like I can move around the cursor in sentence edit, add, delete characters). I want to place the cursor exactly after a specific character.

I am picking up the DOM width using **`.getBBox()`** and **`.getBoundingClientRect`** and maintaining the cursor position but I am facing a problem when I am trying to edit in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: In order to find the width of a char in SVG you may use the `getExtentOfChar` method. There is also a `getSubStringLength` method you may use. If this doesn't help please add your code.

Comment: There is a whole range of methods bundled with the [SVGTextContentElement interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTextContentElement).